# How to get numeric before string character in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I have data for example

> 8789 WWW xxx 8739

and if the value like this, the value still 786-456 not 786

> 786-456

I want to get numeric before string character, how to do that?

the result should be

> 8789
>
> 786-456

here is the code that I have made

```
$string = '123 home/cat1/subcat2/';
$first = strtok($string, "/^[a-zA-Z]");
echo $first;
```

the result that I want should be

> 123

Comment: Have you tried anything? We're glad to help you sort any issues out with your existing code, but we're not here to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply cast it into an int, which will convert as much as it can before encountering a non-int character.

```
$str="8789 WWW xxx 8739";
echo (int)$str;//outputs 8789
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of abusing behaviours like this, I hope that at some point PHP starts creating some form of error/warning when people just cast things like this to an int and not do a 'proper' conversion.

Comment: @Dimi thanks for your help, but how if I want to keep the value with 234-897, so the value is still 234-897 not 234?

Comment: @silviazulinka I am already getting flak for giving out answers to low-effort questions but... depending on how your data is structured you can either do `strtok($str,' ');`, which will get everything before first empty space or do this regex `[0-9\-]+`