# how to get substring everything before alphabet in php?

Tags: php, regex

I tried to find a way to get all the numeric characters before the alphabet characters. Here are some examples of strings below.

```
1234-89783
453 S2 342
3456j5 789
```

so i need to get value from data above using regex, the result should be 1234-89783, 453, 3456.

value after alphabet character deleted, and remove space if there is space before alphabet. 453 S2 342 to 453 with no space at the end character.

Comment: *but i cant do that* - what do you cant ?

Comment: You should at least attempt to solve it yourself and you definitely shouldn't [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57677269).

Comment: `-` is not a numeric character.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus ... slight nitpick ... it kinda is, in an signed int, just not how it's being used here ;)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I just want to get value before alphabet a-z or A-Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the first alpha character and everything after it.

```
$output = preg_replace('/ *[A-Za-z].*/s', '', $input);
```

Comment: `.` does not  match line breaks by default, so `preg_replace('/ *[A-Za-z].*/', '', $input)` will fail to remove all text after the first letter if there a line breaks.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks! I was just thinking of a set of separate short strings, but that's a great point.

Comment: An `i` pattern modifier would be good here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_split](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$data = [
    "1234-89783",
    "453 S2 342",
    "3456j5 789",
];

$output = [];

foreach ($data as $item):
    $split = preg_split("/[A-Za-z]+/", $item);
    $output[] = $split[0];
endforeach;

print_r($output);
```

This splits the inputstring by a regular expression, in this case lowercase and upper case letters.

In the example above, we push the 0th item from our `preg_split` into an array. Depending on what you want to do with the output, you might need to clean off the white space with `trim()`. So to output a comma seperated string like in your question, you could do something like:

```
foreach ($data as $item):
    $split = preg_split("/[A-Za-z]+/", $item);
    $output[] = trim($split[0]);
endforeach;

echo implode(", ", $output);
```

Which would output:

```
1234-89783, 453, 3456
```

Comment: These `preg_split()` calls are missing their `$limit` parameter.

Answer (score -1):

try this also

```
<?php 
    $string="1234-89783 453 S2 342 3456j5 789";
    $res = preg_replace("/[^-0-9\s]/", "", $string);

    echo $res;

?>
```

Comment: This unexplained answer will smash all digits together -- this is not what the asker is calling for.  This answer is provably incorrect.